# React UseEffect lista assíncrona não renderiza

Tags: array, react, typescript, async

Estou com problema de uma lista assíncrona não aparecer quando o componente é iniciado. Essa lista não aparece mesmo eu dando refresh no navegador, mas se eu der um **CRTL + S** no meu código (pro react atualizar), a lista funciona.

```js
import React, { FormEvent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Search from './components/Search/Search.components';
import PokeList from './components/PokeList/PokeList.component';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { getPokemons, Pokemon } from './models/pokemon.models';

function App() {

  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState<Array<Pokemon>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemons().then(response => setPokemons(response))
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PokeList pokemons={pokemons} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Imagino que seja algo relacionado a fazer uma chamada assíncrona dentro do useEffect.

```js
import { Pokemon } from "../../models/pokemon.models";

type PokeListProps = {
  pokemons: Array<Pokemon>
}

function PokeList({ pokemons }: PokeListProps) {
  return (
    <>
      {pokemons.map((p, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <div >{p.name}</div>
            <img src={p.image} /> 
            <hr />
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default PokeList;
```

As funções get funcionam perfeitamente

```js
export type Pokemon = {
  id: Number,
  name: string,
  image: string
}

async function getPokemon(url: string): Promise<Pokemon> {
  const res = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
  const pokemonId = res.id

  const pokemon: Pokemon = {
    id: pokemonId,
    name: res.forms[0].name,
    image: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemonId}.png`
  }

  return pokemon
}

export async function getPokemons(): Promise<Array<Pokemon>> {
  const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=20').then(response => response.json())
  const pokemonsJSON = response.results
  var pokemons:Array<Pokemon> = []

  pokemonsJSON.forEach(async (p:any) => {
    const pokemon = await getPokemon(p.url)
    pokemons.push(pokemon)
  });

  return pokemons
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver aqui pessoal, o problema era na verdade na função getPokemons.

```js
export async function getPokemons(): Promise<Array<Pokemon>> {
  const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=20').then(response => response.json())
  const pokemonsJSON = response.results
  
  let pokemons: Array<Pokemon> = await Promise.all(
    pokemonsJSON.map(async (p: any) => {
      const newPokemon = await getPokemon(p.url)
      return newPokemon
    }
  ))

  return pokemons
}
```

Estava tentando adicionar cada elemento na lista com um push padrão, mas como estava dentro de um loop, estava fazendo uma chamada assíncrona e não estava adicionando na lista. Resolvi usando esse Promise.All(). Ficou desse jeito:

```js
function App() {

  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState<Array<Pokemon>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemons().then(res => setPokemons(() => [...res]))
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PokeList pokemons={pokemons} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que isto resolva :)

```
const getPokemons = useCallback( async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151')
  const data = await response.json()
  setPokemons(data)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  getPokemons()
}, [])
```

Comment: Tipo, o que eu estou tentando fazer na verdade é botar as funções de chamada de api em um arquivo ts separado. Faço isso porque primeiro transformo os objetos da api em tipos Pokemon ( que eu criei ), depois utilizo no meu componente.

Answer (score -3):

tenta atualizar seu código para funcionar assim.
Por padrão, o React não aceita que essa função useEffect seja do tipo assíncrona.
Voce precisa contornar esse problema de alguma outra forma.
Eu atualizaria meu codigo para algumas dessas duas opções.

```
  async function getApi() {
    return await getPokemons();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const response = getApi();
     setPokemons(response)
  }, []);
```

Ou

```
(async () => {
   const response= await getPokemons();
   setPokemons(response)
})();
```